# Spring batch Kafka Remote Chunking processing two different csv feed files & writing the two feeds data into two tables in single job

Tags: java, spring, csv

I am developing a Spring batch Remote Chunking processing with Kafka Broker

### Master:

1. reader reads the two csv files, preparares POJO1, POJO2 Objs for the two csv feed files.
2. writer, writes the two pojos into Kafka broker over a topic.

Getting getting below exception in Master process

```
org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.AsynchronousFailureException: Failure or interrupt detected in handler: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassCastException: model.POJO1 cannot be cast to model.POJO2
```

### Slave:

Reader: 1. How to read the Messages from Kafka into to POJOs from the topic?
2. How to Convert the Messages into two Pojo Objects?

Processor: some data processing logic

Writer: writes the pojo1 to T1 table , Pojo2 to T2 table

Please guide me I am new to Spring Batch & Kafka Integration